# Can someone suggest good books or resources on SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, books

I'm trying to find a resource on SparkR specifically so that I can learn about the subtleties in it. But there doesn't seem to be much, other than the docmentation.  I found a book called Mastering Spark in R but that uses sparklyr.  I'm not sure if I should just read a book on Spark in general (which would probably use python or sparklyr) or whether I should just stick to the documentation of SparkR (which is honestly not very good).  So I'm hoping there are resources targeted towards SparkR

Comment: Asking for book recommendations is generally [off-topic](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This is due mostly to answers being opinion-based, which is likely to generate a discussion rather than a clear answer.

Comment: @JohnPolo Well I did consider the possibility that it might be viewed as off topic, but I have seen many posts with lots of upvotes on here asking for book and resource recommendations. In any case...I have not been able to find *any* books on SparkR which is why I'm asking this community.  I'm not looking for a discussion on the merits of one book vs another.